# Which preposition should be used in "He did well {in/at} high school"?

Tags: prepositions

What's the preposition in the sentence

> He did very well in/at high school.

Some differentiate between the two prepositions, some say it's negligible. Which one is accepted?

What about university:

> He was an average student in high school but really did well at university.

Comment: Yes, this sounds good. While I liked @Astralbee's answer (well written), it didn't sound good--or maybe it was British-biased.

Answer (score 1):

There are contexts where the two prepositions are interchangeable, and others where they are not.

For example, they tend to be interchangeable when talking about *attendance* or *presence* at school:

> - John is at school today
> - John is in school today

But "at school" means more than just being *currently* present in school. It idiomatically means that someone is of school age, *normally* attending school.

For example:

> -Is your son at school yet?
> -No, he's only 2.

In your example, which talks about someone's historic performance, "at school" is most appropriate, because it would idiomatically refer to his period of schooling rather than just the hours he was physically present "in" his school. Saying "he did well in school" just doesn't sound right - it could be taken to mean that he *didn't* do well when he was outside of school (eg at home).

Comment: There is a British/American difference - see [this earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/250991/at-school-vs-in-school).

Comment: So it seems: it sounds better to me "in school" (and most links suggest that "at" refers to physically present), which is the opposite of what and Astralbee (British) thinks.

Answer (score -2):

I'm in  high school = you're studying in highschool
I'm at highschool = you're in highschool exactly places.

Comment: This is unclear and not authoritative enough for an answer.

Comment: When you provide answers about English usage, please write correctly and idiomatically. "Exactly places" is almost meaningless.